# Tucson 2013 Heatup oil water mixed

Tags: radiator, tucson

[image]

Engine Oil is Ok but Rediator water mixing with Oil..

4 weeks before machanic suggested to change the Rediator.

After that same issue happening again.

I don't beleive on machanic anymore, what i need to do again?

Comment: The most common place water and oil get in close proximity is the head gasket and cylinder head. Are you having rough running problems or overheating issues?

Comment: Just overheating issue. non rough running issue

Comment: looks like gearbox oil friend. check gearbox cooler.